# Fetching emails from various clients to store in a database

Tags: java, beginner, email

I have written code which does the following:

1. The main goal is to fetch emails from inbox and spam folders and store them in a database. It fetches emails from Gmail, GMX, web.de, Yahoo and Hotmail.

   The following attributes are stored in a MySQL database:

   `Slno`, `messagedigest`, `messageid`, `foldername`, `dateandtime`, `receiver`, `sender`, `subject`, `cc`, `size` and `emlfile`.
2. For Gmail, GMY and web.de, I have used the JavaMail API because email from it can be fetched with IMAP.
3. For Yahoo and Hotmail, I have used an HTML parser and HTTP client to fetch emails from the spam folder, and for the inbox folder, I have used the POP3 JavaMail API.

I want to have a proper class hierarchy which makes my code efficient and easily reusable. I am sure it can still be improved, so I would like to have different opinions on it.

I have the following classes and methods as of now:

1. `MainController` - Here I pass `emailid`, `password` and `foldername` from which emails have to be fetched.
2. Abstract class - `EmailProtocol`

   Abstract methods of it (all methods except `executeParser` contains method definition):

   - `connectImap()` - used by GMX, Gmail and web.de email IDs
   - `connectPop3()` - used by Hotmail and Yahoo to fetch emails from the inbox folder
   - `createMessageDigest` - used by every email provider (GMX, Gmail, web.de, Yahoo, and Hotmail)
   - `establishDBConnection` - used by every email
   - `emailAlreadyExists` // used by every email which checks whether email already exists in db or not, if not then store it.
   - `storeemailproperties` - used by every email to store emails properties to MySQL database
   - `executeParser` - nothing written in it. Overridden and used by just Hotmail and Yahoo to fetch emails from the spam folder.
3. `Imap extends EmailProtocol`

   There's nothing in it, but I have to have it to access methods of `EmailProtocol`. This is used to fetch emails from Gmail, GMX and web.de. I know this is really a bad way but don't know how to do it another way.
4. `Hotmail extends EmailProtocol`

   Methods:

   - `executeParser()` - This is used by just a Hotmail email ID.
   - `fetchjunkemails()` - This is also very specific for only a Hotmail email ID.
5. `Yahoo extends EmailProtocol`

   Methods:

   - `executeParser()`
   - `storeEmailtotemptable()`
   - `MoveEmailtoInbox()`
   - `getFoldername()`
   - `nullorEquals()`

   All above methods are specific for a Yahoo email ID.
6. `public DateTimeFormat(class)`

   - `format()` - This formats datetime of GMAX, Gmail and web.de emails.
   - `formatYahoodate` - This formats datetime of Yahoo email.
   - `formatHotmaildate` - This formats datetime of a Hotmail email.
7. `public StringFormat`

   - `ConvertStreamToString()` - Accessed by every class except the `DateTimeFormat` class.
   - `formatFromTo()` - Accessed by every class except the `DateTimeFormat` class.
8. `public Class CheckDatabaseExistance`

   ```
    public static void checkForDatabaseTablesAvailability()
   ```

   (This method checks at the beginning whether the database and required tables exist in MySQL or not. If not, it creates them.)

Please see my `MainController` class so that you can have an idea about how I use different classes.

```
public class MainController {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<String> web_de_folders = new ArrayList<String>();
        web_de_folders.add("INBOX");
        web_de_folders.add("Unbekannt");
        web_de_folders.add("Spam");
        web_de_folders.add("OUTBOX");
        web_de_folders.add("SENT");
        web_de_folders.add("DRAFTS");
        web_de_folders.add("TRASH");
        web_de_folders.add("Trash");
        
    

ArrayList<String> gmx_folders = new ArrayList<String>();
        gmx_folders.add("INBOX");
        gmx_folders.add("Archiv");
        gmx_folders.add("Entwürfe");
        gmx_folders.add("Gelöscht");
        gmx_folders.add("Gesendet");
        gmx_folders.add("Spamverdacht");
        gmx_folders.add("Trash");
        
        ArrayList<String> gmail_folders = new ArrayList<String>();
        gmail_folders.add("Inbox");
        gmail_folders.add("[Google Mail]/Spam");
        gmail_folders.add("[Google Mail]/Trash");
        gmail_folders.add("[Google Mail]/Sent Mail");
        
        
        ArrayList<String> pop3_folders = new ArrayList<String>();
        pop3_folders.add("INBOX");
            
        CheckDatabaseExistance.checkForDatabaseTablesAvailability();

        EmailProtocol imap = new Imap();
        System.out.println("CHECKING FOR NEW EMAILS IN WEB.DE...(IMAP)");
        System.out.println("*********************************************************************************");
        imap.connectImap("email@web.de", "pwd", web_de_folders);
        
        System.out.println("\nCHECKING FOR NEW EMAILS IN GMX.DE...(IMAP)");
        System.out.println("*********************************************************************************");
        imap.connectImap("email@gmx.de", "pwd", gmx_folders);
        
        System.out.println("\nCHECKING FOR NEW EMAILS IN GMAIL...(IMAP)");
        System.out.println("*********************************************************************************");
        imap.connectImap("email@gmail.com", "pwd", gmail_folders); 
        
        EmailProtocol yahoo = new Yahoo();
        Yahoo y=new Yahoo();
        System.out.println("\nEXECUTING YAHOO PARSER");
        System.out.println("*********************************************************************************");
        y.executeParser("http://de.mc1321.mail.yahoo.com/mc/welcome?ymv=0","email@yahoo.de","pwd");
        System.out.println("\nCHECKING FOR NEW EMAILS IN INBOX OF YAHOO (POP3)");
        System.out.println("*********************************************************************************");
        yahoo.connectPop3("email@yahoo.de","pwd",pop3_folders); 
        
        System.out.println("\nCHECKING FOR NEW EMAILS IN INBOX OF HOTMAIL (POP3)");
        System.out.println("*********************************************************************************");
        yahoo.connectPop3("email@hotmail.com","pwd",pop3_folders);
        
        
        EmailProtocol hotmail = new Hotmail();
        Hotmail h=new Hotmail();
        System.out.println("\nEXECUTING HOTMAIL PARSER");
        System.out.println("*********************************************************************************");
        h.executeParser("https://login.live.com/ppsecure/post.srf","email@hotmail.com","pwd"); 
        
        
    }

}
```

I have kept the `DatetimeFormat` and `StringFormat` classes `public` so that I can access their `public` methods by just `DatetimeFormat.formatYahoodate` for e.g. from different methods.

Answer (score 4):

Well, for starters, I would put the mailbox information into a configuration file, properties file, database table, etc. Anywhere besides hard coded.

Second, your `main()` method is totally out of control and needs to be broken up. I would suggest reading up about refactoring in general, but [here](http://www.devdaily.com/java/refactoring-extract-method-java-example) is a bit that discusses *Extract Method* which is one of your more basic and crucially important refactorings.